# insert item one table to another table mvc entity

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, entity

I want to copy items from one one db table to another table, I have model, two db tables, but when I run view I got error, in the below my model, tables and controller and view,

my model is

```
public IEnumerable<sepetUrun> sepetUruns { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<sepetMusteri> sepetMusteris { get; set; }
```

sepetUrun db is

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UrunAdi { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UrunAdet { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> UrunTutar { get; set; }
        public string UrunKod { get; set; }
```

sepetMusteri db is

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MusteriAdi { get; set; }
        public string MusteriKod { get; set; }
```

my controller is

```
            public ActionResult FaturaHazirla2()
        {
            UrunMusteriVM urunMusteriVM = new UrunMusteriVM();

            urunMusteriVM.sepetUruns = db.sepetUrun.ToList();

            urunMusteriVM.sepetMusteris = db.sepetMusteri.ToList();

            return View(urunMusteriVM);
        }

        public ActionResult Onay2(FaturaMus p, Fatura dp, string MusteriAdi, string MusteriKod, string UrunAdi, int UrunAdet, decimal UrunTutar, string UrunKod)
        {
            p.MusteriAdi = MusteriAdi;
            p.MusteriKod = MusteriKod;

            dp.FaturaUrunAdi = UrunAdi;
            dp.FaturaMiktar = UrunAdet;
            dp.FaturaTutar = UrunTutar;
            dp.FaturaUrunKod = UrunKod;

            db.FaturaMus.Add(p);
            db.Fatura.Add(dp);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View("FaturaHazirla2");
        }
```

my view is

```
    <form action="/Satis/Onay2/">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Müşteri Adı</th>
            <th>Müşteri Kodu</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.sepetMusteris)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.MusteriAdi, new { @readonly = "readonly", name = "MusteriAdi2" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.MusteriKod, new { @readonly = "readonly", name = "MusteriKod2" })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Ürün Adı</th>
            <th>Ürün Miktarı</th>
            <th>Ürün Tutarı</th>
            <th>Ürün Kodu</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.sepetUruns)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.UrunAdi, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.UrunAdet, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.UrunTutar, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.UrunKod, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <div><button class="btn btn-primary">Onayla</button></div>
</form>
```

but when I run this I gotten this error

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'UrunAdet' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 
'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Onay2(WebApplication1.Models.FaturaMus, WebApplication1.Models.Fatura, System.String, System.String, System.String, Int32, System.Decimal, System.String)' in 'WebApplication1.Controllers.SatisController'. 
An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

how can I solve this

Answer (score 0):

fix the model

```
public List<sepetUrun> sepetUruns { get; set; }
public List<sepetMusteri> sepetMusteris { get; set; }
```

add the model to the view, and since you want to submit data , you have to use for loop instead of foreach

```
@model UrunMusteriVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("UrunMusteriVM", "Satis", FormMethod.Post)) 
{ 
  .....

   @for (var i=0; i < Model.sepetMusteris.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.sepetMusteris[i].MusteriAdi)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.sepetMusteris[i].MusteriKod)</td>
            </tr>
        }
  

        ... the same for another table....
   
 <div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Onayla</button></div>

}
```

and fix the action

```
 public ActionResult Onay2(UrunMusteriVM model)
{
....
}
```

Comment: Dear Serge; I cannot fix actionresult parts could you give me some more details pls,

Comment: @MehmetGÜL I can not help you because I don' t know what is FaturaMus p, Fatura dp, and where did you take them

Comment: FaturaMus is "public partial class FaturaMus
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MusteriAdi { get; set; }
        public string MusteriKod { get; set; }
        public string FaturaNo { get; set; }
    }" and Fatura is "public partial class Fatura
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FaturaUrunAdi { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> FaturaMiktar { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> FaturaTutar { get; set; }
        public string FaturaUrunKod { get; set; }
        public string FaturaNo { get; set; }
    }"

Comment: @MehmetGÜL What it has to do with your view model?

Comment: I need to insert sepetUrun and sepetMusteri db tables items to the Fatura and FaturaMus db tables,

Comment: Because of that I combine two sepetUrun and sepetMusteri db tables in on model than try to insert these tables items to another db Fatura and FaturaMus db tables. after that I delete items in the first ones (sepetUrun and sepetMusteri) these tables are temporary tables